# Dropdown list Refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have dropdownlist with previous date vlaues to open the url with selected value.When i select the value from dropdown it open the url in new window and when i refresh the page it reopen the same url.I want open to open the url in new tab and prevent to reopen the url on refresh My code is bellow

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("var w = window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num={0}','_newtab');", DropDownList1.SelectedValue), True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide name and replace flag to the window (in window.open method), it won't open the same URL in the other window. You can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("var w = window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num={0}','_blank');", DropDownList1.SelectedValue), True)

Comment: It does not provide the name to the window. IE and other browser also look for the named window and if they find that it is opened they used the same. I hope my answer does not misguide you.

Comment: But i dnt understand ur answer please translate my code with accurate keyword

Comment: I have changed my answer. if you pass "window.open('appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/…{0}','myWindow', true);" to the function, I think it will work for you

Comment: you can check it here     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("var w = window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num={0}','mywindow',true);", DropDownList1.SelectedValue), True) its is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open method with return false on selected index change event.

Comment: No dear its not working check my code    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("var w = window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num={0}',false);", DropDownList1.SelectedValue), True)